# Wamp Server shortcut is missing

Tags: windows-7, wamp

The Wamp Server icon(shortcut), that was im my Desktop, is missing.
The folder still there (C:\wamp).
I restarted my PC and it was no longer there.
Any idea why did it happen?
My computer it is not shared, and there are no .exe in wamp folder.

I'm using W7

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a new chortcut by right clicking on desktop and New -> Shortcut... and the path put in C:\WAMP\WAMP.EXE. The why it happened... if the computer is a shared computer it could of been removed by another person.

Comment: No it is not shared, and there is no .exe in wamp folder =x

Comment: it is also possible that AV software could of "cleaned" it up... you might need to just reinstall WAMP

Comment: How can i save my database files?

Comment: [wampserver.com|backup database](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,56695) - here you go :)